# iOS simulator, dual monitor & rotation issue

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode, osx-spaces

I've got two monitors, with iOS simulator is on a secondary monitor. Xcode is full-screen on a primary monitor (iMac). Whenever I rotate simulator on a secondary display, primary display goes off the full-screen to "Desktop 1". Doesn't matter whether I use shortcuts (<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>) or menu items without keyboard.

At first I thought that may be it conflicts with "switch space" shortcut, so I changed rotation shortcuts to <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>, still same annoying behaviour.

Any ideas how this can be fixed, so full-screen space on primary monitor doesn't change on simulator rotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try (deleting or renaming) the \Library\Application Support\iPhone Simulator folder entirely from this location and run the simulator from XCode.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, didn't help, unfortunately.